# Function with parameters in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create a function called "compNumbers" that takes 2 double numbers. If the two numbers are equal, they should return 0, if the first parameter is greater than the second, it should return 1, if second parameter is greater than the first, it should return -1

Here's my attempt on the question:

```
static double compNumbers(double x, double y)
{
    if (x == y)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (x > y)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (y > x)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double a = 0, b = 0;
    compNumbers(a,b);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The error I'm experiencing is:

**The description says "Program.compNumbers(double,double): not all code paths return a value".**

Also, since I'm new to programming, where would I put the 'input, processing, output' code? I'm confused on where to start...

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Since there are only 3 possible outcomes, change the last one to "else" rather than "else if (y > x)".

Comment: the compiler doesn't know that these are the only three possibilities. it understands the if statements as 3 if statements and it isn't sure what is to be done of all 3 fail

Answer (score 2):

For example, if `x` or `y` has value `double.NaN`, all your conditions will return `false`, so you will reach the end of function and you need to return somethig:

```
static double compNumbers(double x, double y)
{
    if (x == y)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (x > y)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (y > x)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return double.NaN
}
```

More about `double.NaN` value: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(v=vs.110).aspx

To compare double values correct use special method `CompareTo`:

```
x.CompareTo(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
static double compNumbers(double x, double y)
{
    return x.CompareTo(y);
}
```

Comment: Id want my 76 characters back :)

Comment: `static double compNumbers(double x, double y) => x.CompareTo(y)`. I had to too

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're experiencing is that there's no return if all of the else if's are false.

Since the only other option if "x doesn't equal y" and "x isn't larger than y" is "y must be larger than x", I'd remove the last else if and save a few lines of code by just returning -1.

```
static double compNumbers(double x, double y)
{
    if (x == y)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (x > y)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in this case, you don't have to declare a method as `double` because you 
only want an `int` in return!!!

Second, you have to return something when all the conditions are false!!

```
static int? CompNumbers(double x, double y) //int? is nothing more than nullable int
    {
        if (x == y)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (x > y)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (y > x)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return null; //this is the return value you have give !!
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());//taking input from user 
        double b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());//taking input from user
        int? result = CompNumbers(a, b);//assigning result to the return value of CompNumbers   and  int? is nothing more than nullable int
        if (result == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Method returned 0");
        }
        else if (result == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Method returned 1");
        }
        else if(result == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Method returned -1");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

this might be helpful !!